# Why is the default terminal width 80 characters?

Tags: terminal, language-agnostic

80 seems to be the default in many different environments and I'm looking for a technical or historical reason. It is common knowledge that lines of code shouldn't exceed 80 characters, but I'm hard pressed to find a reason why outside of "some people might get annoyed."

Comment: Some of us still remember punch cards, fortran coding forms, and IBM 3270 terminals.

Comment: IBM's most popular punch card.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_cards#IBM_80_column_punched_card_format

Comment: Being born in recent history definitely leaves me at a disadvantage here.

Comment: Well, it starts with the width of chariot wheels ...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As per Wikipedia:

> 80 chars per line is historically descended from [punched
>   cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card#IBM_80-column_punched_card_formats_and_character_codes)
>   and later broadly used in monitor text mode

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_per_line

**Shall I still use 80 CPL?**

Many developers argue to use 80 CPL even if you could use more. Quoting from: http://richarddingwall.name/2008/05/31/is-the-80-character-line-limit-still-relevant/

> Long lines that span too far across the monitor are hard to read. This
>   is typography 101. The shorter your line lengths, the less your eye
>   has to travel to see it.
>
> If your code is narrow enough, you can fit two files on screen, side
>   by side, at the same time. This can be very useful if you’re comparing
>   files, or watching your application run side-by-side with a debugger
>   in real time.
>
> Plus, if you write code 80 columns wide, you can relax knowing that
>   your code will be readable and maintainable on more-or-less any
>   computer in the world.
>
> Another nice side effect is that snippets of narrow code are much
>   easier to embed into documents or blog posts.

As a Vim user, I keep `ColorColumn=80` in my `~/.vimrc`. If I remember correctly, Eclipse autoformat <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, breaks lines at 80 chars by default.

[image: Vim with ColorColumn enabled. Right-Click > Open Image in new tab for larger image]

Answer (score 18):

It is because IBM punch cards were 80 characters wide.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I appreciate the links given in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your computer probably doesn't have a punch card reader, but it probably does have `lpr(1)` which follows the convention set by IBM for punch cards.  The `lpr(1)` command defaults to Courier font with margins set for 80-columns and 8-space tabs for plain text files on 8.5"x11" paper.  Try `cat foo.c | lpr` and if the author of `foo.c` used conventional line width and source code formatting rules, then the printed page will look mostly readable.  Otherwise, best not to kill the trees.

Comment: My answer has the added virtue of not being merely of historical interest.  There are still valid *technical* reasons to use 80-column width formatting for source files wherever there are people who still print source code using the command line tools and expect to be able to read it.

Answer (score 3):

One of the characteristics of good typography is properly set *measure* - length of the line of characters.

> There is an optimum width for a Measure and that is defined by the amount of characters are in the line. A general good rule of thumb is 2-3 alphabets in length, or **52-78** characters (including spaces).

It simply makes sense to make your text readable.

See [Five simple steps to better typography](http://www.markboulton.co.uk/journal/comments/five-simple-steps-to-better-typography) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly the old dot matrix printers were only able to print 80 characters across. I am pretty sure my old commodore 64 and 128 had the same 80 characters, now that I think about it, I don't think the monitor could display more than 80 characters either

> The LA30 was a 30 character/second dot
>   matrix printer introduced in 1970 by
>   Digital Equipment Corporation of
>   Maynard, Massachusetts. It printed 80
>   columns of uppercase-only 5x7 dot
>   matrix characters across a
>   unique-sized paper.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_matrix_printer

Comment: Commodore64 (as apple ][) could natively handle only 40 standard characters (horizontal resolution was 320). To get 80 means using 4 pixels per character monochrome (the hardware could handle two colors for every 8x8 cell). Higher resolution wouldn't have been practical anyway as most most users only had television that can't be used seriously with 80 characters and at that time also the video signal was transmitted by a modulator (no direct vga input) that sure doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

possibly due to screen resolution of 640 pixels..
each character is or was 8 pixels wide giving you 640 (80x8)

Comment: Other way around, the screen resolution was 640x480 because that was big enough for two punch cards…