# Console Width; Assume Default Or Be Made An ...?

Tags: c++, cin

Reading input from the console

```
if(std::cin){
    decision = std::cin.get();

    if(std::cin.eof())
        throw CustomException("Error occurred while reading input\n");
}else{
    throw CustomException("Error occurred while reading input\n");
}
```

Purging remaining input on the stream

```
std::cin.ignore(COL_WIDTH, '\n'); // skip bad input
```

`COL_WIDTH` is 80 as determined through [Why is the default terminal width 80 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651012/why-is-the-default-terminal-width-80-characters). Should I assume an 80 character console width or is an arbitrarily larger number more appropriate for `cin.ignore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter more than a row of characters, even if it is 80.
 Use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead.