# What is the 80 columns rule?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently a high school student and I have to create a website about tourism in my computer sciences class. On my criteria sheet, my teacher has written "Code should strive to fit into 80 columns where possible for ease of printing". I have tried to search for an answer and I found out that it is some sort of rule but I can't wrap my head around what this means. Can anybody help me out? Any examples would be great.

Comment: Well that was easy [**Google Search**](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=80%20columns%20rule&es_th=1)

Comment: This means you should be able to view your code on smaller screen without having to scroll left & right... If you use an editor with columns bar a.k.a Ruler ... You would be able to see where that 80 columns ends.

Answer (score 2):

Like many rules of thumb, it is at least partly based on opinion.  It derives from the widespread use of 80-column punched cards and video terminals through the mid-1990s.  And like other rules, it has been discussed at length -- here:

- [EightyColumnRule](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EightyColumnRule)
- [Is the 80 character limit still relevant in times of widescreen monitors? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/604/is-the-80-character-limit-still-relevant-in-times-of-widescreen-monitors)
- [Why is 80 characters the 'standard' limit for code width?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width)

Answer (score 1):

For me it's about the length of a row of code. The 80 columns it's a standard.

You can see more informations about that in [this question of StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651012/why-is-the-default-terminal-width-80-characters)

So for me you just need to respect the standard of 80 character by line.

PS: For the example look the picture in the link.